# MongoDB: Update nested data, but avoid multiple objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I try to insert some data into an existing document:

```
Graph.update(
    { id: id }, 
    {
        $push: {
            tooltips: {
                element: Session.get('tooltipID'),
                text: text
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This is working quite well, but if there is already data in tooltips, this one should be updated instead of adding a new object, as there can only be a unique object for a unique element (tooltipID).

I want to avoid these multiple entries for the same element-value in tooltips.

```
{
    "_id" : "c4bKur6TKcgFHGLZZ",
    "data" : "[]",
    "tooltips" : [
        {
            "element" : "2d4edaaf",
            "text" : "Lorem"
        },
        {
            "element" : "2d4edaaf",
            "text" : "ipsum"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it should be possible to have more then one object in tooltips, if element is really unique...

I tried to add a `upsert:true` to the update(), but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely `upsert` won't work with embedded document.

One approach can be

```
Graph.update({id:id}, 
    {
       $addToSet: {
           'tooltips': {
              element: Session.get('tooltipID'),
              text: text
            }
       }
})
```

It will ensure no duplicate on tooltips;

similarly you can use `$set`

```
Graph.update({
  id:id,
 'tooltips.element': Session.get('tooltipID')
  }, 
  {
 $set: {
    'tooltips.$.text':text
   }
})
```

or you can pull before push

```
Graph.update({
    "id":id
}, {
    $pull: {
        'tooltips': {
            "element": Session.get('tooltipID')
        }
    }
})
    Graph.update(
    { id: id }, 
    {
        $push: {
            tooltips: {
                element: Session.get('tooltipID'),
                text: text
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I updated the text in the post, as I think it was not clear enough: There can be more then one object in `tooltips`, but they must have unique element-values. So if the tooltipID is already existing, this object-text should be updated, otherwise it will be added.

Comment: The first one checks - as you said - for duplicates on tooltips. And the second one works just for the case there is already an object for tooltips. Then it will be updated. But it doesn't add a new object, if it doesn't exist.

Comment: As we can't upsert on child, you can use 3rd option which will pull the existing one and insert new one, definitely it is not optimal, if you have to update large tooltips. but might direct you on the way.  BTW, if I get time to dig further then will post here.